# Proving the function $ f $ is continuous on $ [0,1] $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, cantor-set

I'm trying to prove that the following function $ f $ is continuous on $ [0,1] $. The function $ f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1] $ is defined as follows.

Let $ x\in [0,1] $.
Then $ x= \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  \frac{a_n}{3^n} $ ; where $ a_{n}\in \{0,1,2\}$ for each $ n\in \mathbb{N} $.

If $ x\in C $ (the Cantor set) then $ x $ can be written as of the form $ \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  \frac{a_n}{3^n} $ ; where $a_{n}\in \{0,2\}$  for each $ n\in \mathbb{N} $ and then we define $ f(x)=\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  \frac{a_n}{2^{n+1}} $;(in this case we use the ternary expansion of $x$ which does not contain 1s to define the function $f$ ).

If $ x\notin C $ then there exists $ n_{0}\in \mathbb{N} $ such that $ a_{n_{0}}=1 $.

Put $ N=\min \{n_{0}\in \mathbb{N}:a_{n_{0}}=1\} $.

If $ N=1 $ then define $ f(x)=\dfrac{1}{2} $ and otherwise we define  $ f(x)=f(\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  \frac{a_n}{3^n})=\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{N-1}  \frac{a_n}{2^{n+1}}+\dfrac{1}{2^{N}} $.

**My attempt:** Let $ x\in [0,1] $ be arbitrary. Then either $ x\in C $ or $ x\notin C $. If $ x\notin C $ then $x$ belongs to some open middle third (say $I$) which has removed in the construction of the Cantor set C. Since $f$ is constant on the open interval $I$, $f$ is obviously continuous at $x$.

But I'm stuck on the Proving that $f$ is continuous at $x$ if $ x\in C $.

Could anyone give me some help ?

Any hints/ideas are much appreciated.

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: Show that $f$ is monotonic. Then you know that $f$ can have at worst jump discontinuities. Then show that $f$ makes no jumps.

Comment: Remember to show that your function is well defined. Your representation of $x$ by the $a_n$ is not well defined, since (for example) $a_1=1,\ a_n=0$ for $n>1$ gives the same $x$ as $a_1=0,\ a_n=2$ for $n>1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks a lot :) I understand your approach.

Comment: @DanielFischer How does one prove that there are "no jumps"? How is that defined analytically?

Comment: @Nilknarf Since we're looking at a monotonically increasing (non-strictly) function, "making no jumps" means $\inf \{ f(y) : y > x\} = f(x)$ and $\sup \{ f(y) : y < x\} = f(x)$ for all $x$ [at the endpoints, only one of the conditions applies].

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah, I see. Thanks!